# Proof using Cantor Schroeder Bernstein theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{N}\sim\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ using the Cantor Schroeder Bernstein Theorem. So, I know I need to find an injection in both directions. My definition of $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$.

Here is my attempt at the proof for one direction:

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to $ $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ be a function given by $f(n)= (n,0)$. Consider $f(n)=f(m)$. Then $(n,0)=(m,0)$ iff $n=m$. Hence this is an injection.

Does this seem fine for this direction? I am not too sure how to go in the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is fine. Now, consider$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{N}\\(m,n)&\mapsto&2^m3^n.\end{array}$$

Comment: Or a straight bijection with $(n,m) \to (2n+1)2^m$ if we're using number theory..

Comment: @Pam_22R It doesn't depend on primes, but is simpler that way. You could take $6^n5^m$ or $6^m10^n$ but why make things complicated. Henno's solution is not so complicated either. Every integer is an odd number times a power of $2$ (which may be $2^0=1$) - keep dividing by $2$ till you can't any more. He is using the odd numbers for one part and the powers of $2$ for the other - which is neat if you think it through.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Note that some care is required with hitting $0$ - you might want to subtract $1$ to get a bijection.

Comment: @MarkBennet yes, it depends on his exact definition of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Pam_22R you need unique factorisation for integers.

Comment: @Pam_22R This answer gives you an injection, which is what you need to complete your proof. Henno's solution is an injection too, but becomes a bijection if you take $(n,m)$ to $(2n+1)2^m-1$ (just subtract $1$ to make sure that zero is in the range of the function)

Comment: @Pam_22R Well you do need something like that, but since you are dealing with specific small primes there are other ways of proving this if you need to. e.g. divide by $2$ is you can, and if you can't you must have odd=odd.